# How do I remove scratches from bluestone steps?

Tags: stairs, stone, scratches, bluestone

I have some scratches on my front entry bluestone steps. I tried to remove them by brushing with water but they don’t seem to go away.

Any advice on how to remove the scratches?

[image]

Comment: Whatever treatment/fix you chose to go with will probably need to be applied to the entire top and front surfaces of all the steps to ensure that they all appear (close to) the same in color and texture when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies to Fresh Codemonger, mineral oil will darken the steps and will leach back out over time showing the scratches from clearing the snow.

Use Muriatic acid to etch a new surface. I have had some success in removing most of the scratches in other slabs.

You will need to dilute it, apply it with a stiff bristle brush, use gloves and eye protection. It can be bad stuff, if handled improperly. Depending on the strength of the acid, I dilute 1 cup with about 2 gallons of water. I only suggest this as an example for dilution.  As a caution, too strong of solution will yellow the stone or anything it gets on, besides burn real bad if it gets on your skin.

It will also need to be rinsed thoroughly.

[Here](https://www.floorchips.com/pdfdatasheets/muriatic_acid_instructions.pdf) is a online document for etching concrete, which is the same process as etching stone, just that there is not painting going on afterward.

Another way to do it by "flaming" the surface with an acetylene torch after wetting the surface. This is the way the edges were finished on our treads after a saw cut the slabs to size. I am certain the top surface was flamed as well since your tread surfaces are not natural cleft.

If you do choose to do it this way you will need a face shield since the steam created by the flaming sends burning hot flakes of stone popping in the air at high speeds.

Here is a video on it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBSOZPRFte8)

The masonry cement will need to be protected from the extreme heat of the torch, it will cause the mortar in the risers to really blow out. that would NOT be good

Comment: Thanks. Do I apply the muriatic acid on the entire stone or just the scratch area?

Comment: Just the scratch area although with the nature of acid it may want to change the stone there a little bit. I don't think it would be enough to notice, for that matter it's not that much of a stretch t treat the whole step system, it will brighten up the stone and the joints as well. I will add to my answer another way to fix the issue, but it is a drastic step as well

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a mineral oil on a test section.  Stone is porous and will absorb so it should make the white area look darker.  Mineral oil is often used for soap stone counter tops.

I'd go with something like the following link.  Then you'll have more if you need to do this again.  You might end up coating the entire surface of the blue stone with it.  It doesn't go bad and this is food safe.  Baby oil is mineral oil too so the larger grocery store chains should have it as well if you wanted a smaller bottle.

[https://www.amazon.com/Premium-Mineral-Approved-Butcher-Cutting/dp/B01LB7MC4M/ref=sr_1_6?dchild=1&keywords=mineral+oil&qid=1608930917&sr=8-6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LB7MC4M)

Comment: Thanks. Would you recommend any specific brand of mineral oil and where can I buy it ?